# How to get around Norton ConnectSafe blocking a site that is known to be safe?

Tags: wireless-networking, norton-internet-security

I've never installed Norton ConnectSafe, but it's still preventing me from accessing `www.sfml-dev.org`. I know this site is safe because it is the distributor of the commonly used SFML library for C++.

When I try to connect, Norton pops up instead and gives me a warning screen. I try to click “Visit site anyway,” but that just takes me to `http://search.dnsadvantage.com/main?` a page with just a Yahoo! search-bar.

I share my Wi-Fi with my family, and I assume Norton is blocking the site because it's installed on another computer, but I really have no idea how to unblock the site, or if that's even the issue.

I have tried to access this site on multiple browsers and computers in our house and the result is always the same.

Please, tell me how I can access the website, `www.sfml-dev.org`.

Comment: Have you tried adding the site to the exception list?  This sounds like a feature of your router, I am aware of a device by Norton, that would explain this behavior.  Are you using that device?

Comment: @ramhound I'm not sure. I don't have any knowledge of Norton, and I can't access it from my desktop. I run Ubuntu LTS 18.04, but all the other computers run Windows 10. I'm not sure where to start looking.

Comment: Check to see if your router is using [Norton DNS](https://dns.norton.com/configureRouter.html).  This isn't something that is just randomly configured.  You should talk to whom ever configured it before changing it.